# My Listview is exceeding the limits of the screen but I'm using a constraintlayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, formatting

I'm working on an app that displays a list with a custom list item view, and above it has two spinners on top of each other. On my emulator, using a Pixel 3 XL, the formatting works just fine, everything is visible and clickable, and all relative to the edges of the screen. However, when I build the APK and download the app to my phone, an Honor 10, the list and spinners go offscreen on both sides horizontally, and the spinners are pushed offscreen at the top, so the top spinner is not even clickable, and the bottom one is half visible. I'm having a hard time understanding how this could happen considering I'm using a constraint layout on the fragment with the list and spinners in it. Shouldn't it all fit within the limits of the screen, regardless of device, if I'm using a constraint layout?

Here is the xml of the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".results">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/spinner_race_results"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_results"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:padding="8dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_years_results"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_race_results"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner_years_results"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How is it possible that the list is going offscreen on the sides if the layout_width is set to match parent?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share some screenshots of both Pixel 3 XL emulator and from your device